# UserControl inherit from another class to extend it

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, webforms, user-controls

I have a third party control *ClientPeoplePicker*. The problem is that this control cannot be disabled. To disable it, I put the control inside a div with position:relative ("1") and add another with position:absolute and high z-index ("2"). So the aspx structure is:

```
<div id="1">
 <div id=2/>
 <clientpeoplepicker/>
</div>
```

Now, I want to create a user control which will render all of the above and also inherit from ClientPeoplePicker, so I can use inheritance and not have to map properties of ClientPeoplePicker created inside onto the control wrapper. How can I achive this (the best way)? If I merely create an instance inside the user control, to create it in CreateChildControls, I will lose inheritance. Or should I override rendering?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so i went with overriding RenderControl

EDIT:

whole code:

```
    private bool _enabled = true;
    public new bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _enabled;
        }
        set
        {
            _enabled = value;
        }
    }

    Panel divWrapper;
    Panel divBlocker;

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        divWrapper = new Panel();
        divWrapper.ID = base.ClientID + "_divWrapper";
        divWrapper.CssClass = this.CssWraper;

        divBlocker = new Panel();
        divBlocker.ID = base.ClientID + "_divBlocker";
        divBlocker.CssClass = this.CssBlocker;
        if(this.Enabled)
        {
            divBlocker.Style.Add("display", "none");
        }

        divWrapper.RenderBeginTag(writer);
        divBlocker.RenderControl(writer);

        base.RenderControl(writer);

        divWrapper.RenderEndTag(writer);
    }
```

CSS

```
.cpp_blockdiv
{
z-index: 1000;
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #000;
opacity: 0.1;
position: absolute;
}

.cpp_container
{
position:relative;
}
```